# How can I run SSH on a port other than 22?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, port-forwarding

I have a Linux machine on my network. I connect to it using SSH with PuTTY over the Internet, so I have forwarded port 22 to the machine.

Now I need to put another Linux machine on the network. I will want to connect to this new machine using PuTTY as well. I want to run telnet/SSH on it using a port other than 22 so that I can forward it.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are asking. Are you configuring your ssh server or your telnet server?

Comment: Possible dupe of: http://serverfault.com/questions/127234/how-do-i-change-the-ssh-port-to-something-other-than-22

Comment: @studio Off topic?

Comment: @DanielBeck: this was flagged as belonging on SF, and there is already a question like it (see peelman's comment above), so instead of migrating and having it closed there, I just closed it here...

Comment: @studiohack I was confused about going to SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: Having a duplicate on SF doesn't do much for those searching SU for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your ssh server (and Linux distro).

Check out `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (or similar, this is at least in Debian based distributions).

There is line

```
Port 22
```

Change it and restart your sshd (usually `/etc/init.d/ssh restart`, it may be also `/etc/init.d/sshd`).

Comment: looks promising!

Comment: it worked like a charm!

Comment: Noob comment, but if it's commented (# at the beginning), uncomment it (remove the #). BTW, works great!

Answer (score 1):

You are running from outside of the network? (internet connection?) If not you don't need to forward port and just connect with `ssh ip` or `ssh hostname` (or equivalent using putty configurations). If you are out of the network and need port forwarding, you only need to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` server file and change the `#Port 22` line to the port you want and remove comment. After you need to restart ssh on the server.

Comment: sure I am connecting over internet.